# mysql ibdata1 file corrupted or increased unusually

Tags: mysql, innodb, ibdata

We are using MySQL 5.2 version all InnoDB tables.

I have observed that `ibdata1` file got increased very unusually like occupied **500 GB in 2 days**.

In last 6 months, it had taken only 6 GB though there were no inserts at all. I also deleted the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and  `ib_logfile1` and restarted mysql.

It worked fine. but again after 6 months same issue, and the ibdata1 got increased to 550 GB. There are no errors found in error log file.

**I would like to know what may be the reason in general ?**

Comment: Please have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/is-there-any-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql

Comment: 1) Please run `SELECT VERSION();`. 2) Do you have innodb_file_per_table enabled (Please run `SHOW VARAIBLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';`.

Comment: INNODB_FILE_PER_TABLE IS NOT ENABLED..

Comment: Please goto the link in my answer from `Oct 29, 2010` and carry out all the steps in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that ibdata1 is the system tablespace. It is home of the InnoDB Infrastructure. Here are the following classes of information stored in ibdata1.

- Table Data Pages (if [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled)
- Table Index Pages (if [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled)
- Data Dictionary (Tablespace IDs, Logical-to-Physical Mapping to Tables)
- Double Write Buffer (Handles Data Redundancy to Support Crash Recovery)
- Insert Buffer (Handles Updates to Secondary Indexes)
- Rollback Segments (Manages Reverse Engineering of Uncommitted Transactions)
- Undo Space (Containers of Information for Rollback Operations)
- [Click to See Pictorial Representation of the InnoDB Infrastructure](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

As you can see, ibdata1 has a lot of moving parts. The fastest growing section of ibdata1 would be the undo space, especially when there are a lot of read transactions and a few write transactions.

Please read me past posts on doing InnoDB Cleanup:

- `Oct 29, 2010` : [Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757)
- `Nov 26, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)
- `Mar 25, 2012` : [Why does InnoDB store all databases in one file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file/15542#15542)
- `Jun 19, 2012` : [whether a big (but not used) ibdata1 slow anything down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21134/whether-a-big-but-not-used-ibdata1-slow-anything-down/21195#21195)
- `Jan 07, 2013` : [Database space doesn't match ibdata1 size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/database-space-doesnt-match-ibdata1-size/31554#31554)